# How would i add an URL to an Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert some text in my code to a URL but the  tag is not working. Can someone help me with this?

Well want i want is to have the data in my object to become a clickable hyperlink

For instance, i would like for the code and live words to become hyper links

or something like this

```
`{ url: 'http://someurl.com', linkContents: 'this is what goes inside a link tag' }`


then just `<a href={teacher.url}>{teacher.linkContents}</a>`
```

Tried using  Tags

```
const Teachers = () => {
 let teachers = TeacherList.map((teacher) => {
return (
  <li className="teacher" key={teacher.id} >
    <img className="teacher-img" src={teacher.img_src} alt="teacher" />
    <h3>{teacher.name}</h3>

    <p>{teacher.bio}</p>
    <ul className="skills">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>Vanilla Javascript</li>


    </ul>
  </li>

const TeacherList = [
  {
    name: "Catharsis Code Live" ,
    bio: "Angie is a web developer and teacher who is passionate about building scalable, data driven web apps, especially ones that address old problems with new tech!",
    img_src: "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-1"
  },
  {
    name: "NodeStradamus",
    bio: "'NodeStra' is a software engineer and philosopher trying to leave the world better than he found it. He codes for non-profits, eCommerce, and large-scale web apps.",
    img_src: "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-2"
  },
  {
    name: "Geo 'Lo' Cation",
    bio: "Geo is a JavaScript developer working on large-scale applications. He's also a teacher who strives to support students in removing all barriers to learning code.",
    img_src: "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-3"
  },
  {
    name: "Ecma Scriptnstuff",
    bio: "Ecma found her passion for computers and programming over 15 years ago. She is excited to introduce people to the wonderful world of JavaScript.",
    img_src: "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-4"
  },
```

I would like for the Code and Live Text to be hyperLinks

Comment: Where are you closing the `)` after return

Comment: After the </li>

Comment: You're wanting to add an input that allows the user to enter a url for each teacher?

Comment: Well want i want is to have the data in my object to become a clickable hyperlink

Comment: How would i do such?

Comment: @CodingOni you need to add an [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) in your JSX. Currently, your image is being loaded from `teacher.img_src`, but you aren't hyperlinking to anything anywhere.

Comment: You want the whole object to be clickable or just the teacher name?

Comment: What does it mean to "have the data in my object to become a clickable hyperlink". Where would the hyperlink go? There is no "Code" nor "Live Text" in the code you're showing, so what exactly do you want to be a hyperlink? Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Put another way, a "URL to an Object" is a meaningless statement. Objects are represented by portions of memory on the computer, not a web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add both the keys to your teachers array, and use it in `anchor` tag like below:

```
const TeacherList = [
  {
    name: "Catharsis Code Live" ,
    bio: "Angie is a web developer and teacher who is passionate about building scalable, data driven web apps, especially ones that address old problems with new tech!",
    img_src: "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-1",
    someUrl: "http://example.com"
  },
  {
    name: "NodeStradamus",
    bio: "'NodeStra' is a software engineer and philosopher trying to leave the world better than he found it. He codes for non-profits, eCommerce, and large-scale web apps.",
    img_src: "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-2",
    someUrl: "http://example.com"
  },
]

const Teachers = () => {
  let teachers = TeacherList.map(teacher => {
    return (
      <li className="teacher" key={teacher.id}>
        <a href={teacher.someUrl}>
          <h3>{teacher.name}</h3>
        </a>
        <img className="teacher-img" src={teacher.img_src} alt="teacher-img" />

        <p>{teacher.bio}</p>
        <ul className="skills">
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>Vanilla Javascript</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  });
  return teachers;
};
```

Here is a [running demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xxhtqs?file=index.js)

Comment: But this means each teacher will get the same url, im trying to add a url to each teacher object and call for it.

Comment: and you want it to redirect to a different page?

Comment: Yes i would like to redirect to a different page

Comment: I guess I had to have the https with the URL for it to redirect could you explain why?

Comment: yep. because of the mixed content policy. 
see here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have the URL inside the `TeachersList` array object and render it along with teacher name.

Like this.

```
const TeacherList = [
  {
    name: "Catharsis Code Live",
    bio:
      "Angie is a web developer and teacher who is passionate about building scalable, data driven web apps, especially ones that address old problems with new tech!",
    img_src:
      "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-1",
    toUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/users/7194437/prabu-samvel",
    urlText: "stackoverflow-prabusamvel"
  },
  {
    name: "NodeStradamus",
    bio:
      "'NodeStra' is a software engineer and philosopher trying to leave the world better than he found it. He codes for non-profits, eCommerce, and large-scale web apps.",
    img_src:
      "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/24/898316d49dcd721476a0a6ebfd6bef9d-full.png",
    id: "teach-2",
    toUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/users/9084093/marcin-pachole",
    urlText: "stackoverflow-marncinpachole"
  }
];

function Teachers() {
  let teachers = TeacherList.map(teacher => {
    return (
      <li className="teacher" key={teacher.id}>
        <img className="teacher-img" src={teacher.img_src} alt="teacher" />
        <h3>{teacher.name}</h3>
        <a href={teacher.toUrl}>
           <h4>{teacher.textUrl}</h4>
        </a> 
        <p>{teacher.bio}</p>
        <ul className="skills">
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>Vanilla Javascript</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <div>{teachers}</div>;
}
```

Here the [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9158o08qz) and working [demo](https://l9158o08qz.codesandbox.io/)

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to add text within the object  URL For instance Google.com Google

Comment: Yes, you can. you can simply have another object for `urlText` like that to hold the text separately. Check the updated answer and fiddle. @CodingOni